# blocking access to wp-login.php through cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare

I'm trying to block access to my wp-login.php through cloudflare WAF.

I created a firewall rule with the following content:

```
URI path equals /wp-login.php
AND
IP source address equals <my_ipv4>

Action: block
```

As you can see, I'm testing this rule by blocking my own IP-address.

This does not work, I can see wp-login.php still when visiting my website.

A second thing I tried are the IP Access Rules. I blocked my IP for zone "this website", but this also doesn't work.

I got my IP address from this website: https://whatismyipaddress.com/

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start from checking the Security Events, for make sure that you trying to block right IP address.

And second one - need to check your DNS setup. Cloudflare can protect yours endpoint only if you have “Proxied” DNS records: [image].

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this configs:

- URI Full contains wp-login

or

- URI Full contains login